# tsc:1: maximum nested function level reached; increase FUNCNEST?

Tags: typescript, zsh

I'm trying to compile a typescript file, but run into this error:

```
work/gigMax [typescriptMigration●] » tsc src/mutate.ts
tsc:1: maximum nested function level reached; increase FUNCNEST?
work/gigMax [typescriptMigration●] » which tsc
tsc () {
    tsc --target ESNEXT $1
}
```

### Questions:

- what is maximum nested function level?
- What is FUNCNEST?
- how can I fix this and compile from typescript down to javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered the last question by commenting out the tsc function overload in my .zshrc:

```
work/gigMax [typescriptMigration] » tsc src/mutate.ts 
work/gigMax [typescriptMigration●] » which tsc
/home/geoff/.nvm/versions/node/v12.12.0/bin/tsc
```

still curious about the other two questions.